# Website can't show shortcut icon after adding link code?

Tags: html, favicon

I try to add shortcut to my Portfolio web by using code below:

`link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"`

`link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"`

However, it doesn't work. I don't why.

My website is http://wei-xia.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: that works. Thank you! BTW, why i don't need `type="image/x-icon"` in this case?

Comment: I would not know why that's not working but I've never used that before. Even with the way I have sent you can use a JPEG or PNG or GIF too